# Sum of integers between two rows in Hive

Tags: hive

Suppose I have a Hive table that looks like this:

```
 a    b
41   77
8    32
31   76
```

I would like to have another column say `c` which applies a function that loops through all integers between columns `a` and `b`. For example, `c` could contain the sum of all integers between `a` and `b`. Is there a way to phrase my Hive query?

Edit: I'm using `Hive 2.1.1-mapr-1803` version.

Comment: Specify DBMS, including version. Explain why you want this redundant data to be static - or your function is not deterministic in practice?

Comment: Edited to add the Hive version. My function is deterministic but it does not have a closed-form expression. In the example of computingthe sum of integers from `a` to `b` above, I wouldn't want an answer that suggests I use the formula for sum of numbers in an arithmetic progression.

Comment: The sum of consecutive integers between a and b  has a closed form expression though. It is `b(b-1) - a(a+1)`